# MVC: Prefetch Data from Database in Background while showing Login Form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

When a user is not authenticated in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application, he is displayed a login form. After successfully authenticating, he is redirected to the home page where he is displayed the latest data from a table in my MS SQL database.

To speed up the data loading process, I would like to prefetch all data from that database table in the background while showing the login form. That is, I want to immediately serve the view and continue prefetching in the background while the user is entering his credentials. I've tried to use `Task` and `Thread` objects, but I couldn't get the data to load truly asychronously; instead, the login view is only displayed after the loading is finished.

How could I get the data to load asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a `serviceAutoStartProvider` to get/keep your app cache like you want:

[Auto-Start ASP.NET Applications (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Comment: Wow there you go didn't know that existed :) In Gu we trust.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think pre-fetching data for another page based on hitting a login screen really will be the best approach to your problem, if the user login is denied for instance, obviously the pre-fetch was worthless anyway. Plus I don't even think it's possible to kick off a process to populate something you then come back to when you visit the page. Maybe if you use a dependency injection framework like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org) and have a Singleton scope instance perhaps.

Is the data customised based on the logged in user? If the data is not customised based on the logged in user and is simply a static query that is ran, I would look at either caching this data on the home page using the ASP.NET MVC [`OutputCache()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx) attribute and a [small example of it being used](http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2010/12/03/output-caching-with-asp-net-mvc-razor.aspx) if you can afford for it to be cached, if you need up to the minute data, I would probably look at storing the results into an SQL Table or View and just retrieve a flat set of information, which of course will be a lot faster than a complex query which I assume is what is taking up your time.

Comment: The application is only used by about five people and therefore not hit frequently. The database table I'm talking about contains less than 100 rows which only consist of text. Thus, the amount of data that has to be loaded is *really* small. I want to let NHibernate prefetch those ~85 rows, so that the second level cache that it uses is populated once the user finished authenticating. **Bottom line:** I only want to speed up the initial loading; after that, I'm already using `[OutputCache]` etc.